# Lattice, grid.arrange, arrangeGrob, define margins

Tags: r, lattice

I´m trying to dispose 2 lattice barcharts in the same page,

```
graph1<-useOuterStrips(barchart(value1~Var1|Var2+Var3,data=table.df, ylab=NULL)
graph2<-useOuterStrips(barchart(value2~Var1|Var2+Var3,data=table.df, ylab=NULL)
grid.arrange(arrangeGrob(graph1,graph2, nrow=2, ncol=2, left=("percentage"))
```

It works very well, however the left title in to close to the margin and I want to change the margins.

Any clues on how to do that?

Comment: `grid.arrange(arrangeGrob(` makes no sense, you probably want `grid.arrange(graph1, graph2, left=textGrob("percentage", vjust=1, rot=90))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You left textGrob is sized according to the text, you can add a blank line for example:

```
 left=("\n percentage"))
```